# is there is any way to log the response body in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, morgan

I'm trying to create a logger for my own system. I have a problem getting the `res.body`, i am using morgan as a middleware and wrote cutome tokens for getting req and res body, i can easily get the request body but not response body.

```
  morgan.token('qbody', (req) => {
    return JSON.stringify(req.body)
})

morgan.token('sbody', (res) => {

    return JSON.stringify(res.body)
})
```

is there is any way to get the response body?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to log response body in Morgan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191236/is-there-a-way-to-log-response-body-in-morgan)

Comment: not working @Alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using method overloading i sloved this problem

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
var json = res.json
res.json = function (obj) {
    function loging(obj) {
        console.log(obj) //res.body
        console.log(req.body)
    }
    loging(obj)

    json.call(this, obj)
}
next()
})
```